# how to programmatically change the orientation of my modal to landscape

Tags: css, reactjs, meteor, orientation

I am having a parent component and child component in react-meteor where the parent component displays the button which on click opens a modal rendered in child component

Parent component looks something like this:

```
...........
          <child component />
     ..........
```

Child component looks something like this:

```
<Modal
   header='Modal Header'
   trigger={<Button>OR ME!</Button>}>
   <p>Lorem </p>
</Modal>
```

all the screens in my project needs to be in potrait mode except my modal.
I am playing a video using flowplayer in the modal.For mobile version i want my modal to got to 'landscape' mode as soon as it is opened. (or) i want my web-app to go-to landscape mode as soon as my modal is opened and go back to 'potrait' mode when the modal is closed. I have tried using `window.screen.orientation.lock` and `window.screen.lockOrientation(orientation)` 
 but both doesn't work and i have even tried using css `transform: rotate(0.25turn)` but after using this when I am adjusting the modal size `height:100vw(width here)` `width:100vh(height here)` the modal is getting translated to top right corner and going some part of it is going below the screen. How do i solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used `transform-origin` CSS property which solved the problem. I have used view-port units(`vh` and `vw`) for transform origin which worked for different dimensions (responsive).